# Unable to get child of Current User Id for RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to set RecyclerView with Child of Current User Id by using `getCurrentUser().getUid()`.The data structure you can see in image below, [image]

In image above, **SQyOq80egYehjqx4sgiyeNcW8P02** is **current userId** and I want to get all child of those id and show in RecyclerView. In above image, the child is **wed5qPTCdcQVzVlRcBrMo1NX43v1** and their value is **Sep 29, 2018**. My question is how to get those childern values separately and show in RecyclerView. As an example, I wrote code for **Date** (the value of current userId), which gives fatal error. I know error in Model class which I am unable to understand.

**Note:** this line gives error.  `Log.d("sdfsdfdgfdfsdfd", blogPost.getDate());`

Activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = rootRef.child("Friends").child(uid);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BlogPost> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BlogPost>()
                .setQuery(query, BlogPost.class)
                .build();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogPost, BlogPostHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogPostHolder blogPostHolder, int position, @NonNull BlogPost blogPost) {

                Log.d("sdfsdfdgfdfsdfd", blogPost.getDate());
                blogPostHolder.setBlogPost(blogPost);
            }

            @Override
            public BlogPostHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

                return new BlogPostHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter!= null) {
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }

    private class BlogPostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView  userDateTextView;

        BlogPostHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userDateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_date);
        }

        void setBlogPost(BlogPost blogPost) {
            String date = blogPost.getDate();
            userDateTextView.setText(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class BlogPost {
    public String date;

    public BlogPost() {}

    public BlogPost(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

Comment: You don't have child called `date` so you can't get value of child which isn't there. You have `wed5qPTCdcQVzVlRcBrMo1NX43v1a` which is your child instead of that you need child called `date` to be able to get value of  `date`

Comment: then tell me how to get wed5qPTCdcQVzVlRcBrMo1NX43v1 value

Comment: I don't think that is possible using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. You need to use  `query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {...` and create your own `adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wed5qPTCdcQVzVlRcBrMo1NX43v1` in your JSON seems to be dynamic, meaning that each user has a different key. The Firebase client has no way to parse that information into your `BlogPost` class, which only has static properties.

This means you'll have to provide your own `SnapshotParser` class to convert the `DataSnapshot` into the `BlogPost` object. Based on the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/8bda799672d44fd2994d2498441859fae3ccb530/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) that should look something like this:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BlogPost> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BlogPost>()
  .setQuery(query, , new SnapshotParser<Chat>() {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BlogPost parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // first let Firebase read any static properties
        BlogPost post = snapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class); 

        // then do the parsing of the dynamic properties ourselves
        for (DataSnapshot friendSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String friendUID = friendSnapshot.getKey();
            String friendDate = friendSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            post.setDate(friendDate);
        }

        return post;
    }
}).build();
```

The above code is invoked by FirebaseUI for each new snapshot it gets from the database. It first calls `snapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class)` to convert the static parts of the JSON into a `post`, and then parses the friends itself. For now it sets any value it finds to the `date` property of the post. You may need to modify that to fit your exact use-case.

Comment: this gives fatal exception BlogPost post = snapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);

Comment: Yeah, there might be more wrong in your original code there. Since you have no static properties, you might also replace that line with `BlogPost post = new BlogPost();`.

Comment: thanks by changing little bit of code i solved by your answer

Answer (score 1):

change child key in firebase to be date

[image]

Comment: actually my question is how to get all child of SQyOq80egYehjqx4sgiyeNcW8P02

Comment: i dont want to change because this database tell us who is his friend?

Comment: When you push data, push your pojo not only the string data